do Carmo exersise 1-6 2a, an alternative solution?
The problem I am referring to is the following:

to which the solution given at the end of the book is as follows:

I was surprised to find it so different to the solution I worked out myself and I am now wondering weather I have overlooked something. Here is my work:
1-6 2a Without loss of generality we may assume that $\alpha(s)=0$. Let's show that as $h_1, h_2 \to s$ the angle between the osculating plane and the plane passing through the points $\alpha(h_1)$ and $\alpha(h_2)$ goes to zero. Let $\theta(t)$ be the angle between $\alpha(t)$ and the osculating plane. Observe that $\alpha(t)=tT+\frac{kt^2}{2}n+o(t^2)$; therefore, by fixing $\epsilon > 0$ we get, for $t$ in a neighborhood of $0$:
$$
\epsilon|t^2| > \|o(t^2)\| > |\langle o(t^2), b(t) \rangle | = \|\alpha(t) \| |\sin \theta(t)|
$$
(where $b(t)$ is the binormal vector of $\alpha$ at $t$)
from which follows that
$$
|\sin \theta(t)| < \frac{\epsilon |t^2|}{\| tT+\frac{kt^2}{2}n+o(t^2) \| } \xrightarrow{t \to 0} 0 \quad \square$$
Is this a correct solution?
